# struts-jquery does not load dialog content

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2

Have this code:

```
<sj:head compressed="false" jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="custom"/>

 <s:url id="link" action="ABC" namespace="/DEF" escapeAmp="false"/>
 <sj:a openDialog="_dialog" cssStyle="float:left;padding:5 0 0 10;">
                Link
 </sj:a> <sj:dialog id="_dialog" href="%{link}" modal="false" resizable="false" 
                position="center" closeOnEscape="true" draggable="false" title="Contact Us" autoOpen="false">
            </sj:dialog>
```

And when I click the link - it opens the dialog, but the content is empty. And as I see there are no any request made to /DEF/ABC.action.

But, if I change autoOpen attribute to true, - then the dialog opens once page is loaded, and content is there.

What could be the problem, how can I make it work properly?

I've used the struts-jquery examples from http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/DialogTag

Comment: What versions of everything? I recall having an issue w/ dialog contents, I'll see if I can dig up what I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sj:a` tag should look like this: `<sj:a href="%{url}" openDialog="_dialog"/>`
your code should look like this:

```
<sj:head compressed="false" jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="custom"/>

<s:url id="link" action="ABC" namespace="/DEF" escapeAmp="false"/>
<sj:a openDialog="_dialog" href="%{link}" cssStyle="float:left;padding:5 0 0 10;">
    Link
</sj:a>
<sj:dialog id="_dialog"  modal="false" resizable="false" position="center" closeOnEscape="true" draggable="false" title="Contact Us" autoOpen="false" />
```

You should not put `href` in `sj:dialog` tag, it should be in the `sj:a` tag

**UPDATE**

Please check out the [SHOWCASE](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action)